# What's the best workaround for indeterminate progressbar jumping in ICS?

Tags: android, performance, android-layout

I have a custom layout that includes a progress bar above the main ListView. When the list is refreshing, I set the progress bar to be indeterminate. On JellyBean and above, this works nicely. However, in IceCream Sandwich, when set to indeterminate it jumps a few pixels above, enough to hide part of it under the ActionBar.

What would be the best way to work around this behaviour?

Have two progress bars with different marginTop values and switch between them by changing the view visibility when changing between determinate and indeterminate modes? Changing the LayoutParams of the progress bar when changing modes? Or some other way?

In both cases I can do selective handling, such that in the first way I would set up different layouts for different API versions and in the second only change the LayoutParams if SDK_INT value is less than 16.

Is there a better way to work around the behaviour? If not, which of them would be "better"? Here better would probably be in terms of less resource usage and/or maintainability, but I'd also be interested in pros and cons of them.

Comment: First thing you shoud try to understand why it jumps. Is it connected to the drawable resources used? If so you can simply provide your own resources

Comment: Spot on. The drawable for the indeterminate progress bar in ICS has a different height than the one for the determinate progress bar, so the view draws them in slightly different vertical offsets. It was fixed in commit `d0f8ea5` in AOSP. I fixed the problem by including the same assets present in that commit and by setting `android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_indeterminate_horizontal_holo"`. Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Consider setting the progress bar maximum to be the timeout for the refresh. So if you set the timeout to be 60s, use a counter to update the progress bar every second until it times out. Then it will always be a determinant progress bar.